# How to provide tags for some Spring Boot Micrometer metrics but not others?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'm using Spring Boot Micrometer and it produces metrics like `http_server_requests_seconds_bucket`, `http_server_requests_seconds_sum`, `http_server_requests_seconds_count`, `http_server_requests_seconds_max` etc.

I'm using a `WebFluxTagsProvider` to add tags to these metrics

```
@Bean
public WebFluxTagsProvider webFluxTagsProvider() {
  return (serverWebExchange, throwable) -> {
    HttpHeaders headers = serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders();
    return ImmutableList.of(
        Tag.of(
            "my_tag",
            Objects.toString(headers.getFirst("tag_value"), "")));
  };
}
```

The "my_tag" value correctly shows up in all the metrics above.

But the `http_server_requests_seconds_bucket` metric is too high cardinality. It's the one metric that doesn't need "my_tag".

How can I add that tag to all metrics except `http_server_requests_seconds_bucket`?

**EDIT**

I tried this solution but it didn't work but maybe I'm doing it wrong

```
@Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
  return registry ->
      registry
          .config()
          .meterFilter(
              MeterFilter.maximumAllowableTags(
                  "http_server_requests_seconds_bucket",
                  "my_tag",
                  0,
                  MeterFilter.ignoreTags("my_tag")
              ));
}
```

I thought I could set the max tags to be 0 and then ignore it on the fly. Doesn't seem to work but probably not optimal even if it did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with the `MeterFilter` approach. I'm not certain why the approach you attempted didn't work though. It could be due to the fact that Micrometer meters use dot-notation. The underscores you are using look like the metric is how you see in in Prometheus. You could try "http.server.requests", but then that would impact the `_sum`, `_count`, and `_max`.

You might consider creating a separate meter to control tags independently.

Or if you are using Prometheus, you could use a relabel config to drop the unneeded labels. But that could cause collisions with the other buckets, which Prometheus would drop. I'm not certain in that case.

Comment: Yeah, everything you said here is correct. Looks like the solution is to create a separate metric.